# Have one node ignore a CSS class entry

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts, label

So I have the following code snipet which I want applied to 99% of my labels in my JavaFX application. However, sometimes I don't want it applied. Unfortunately whenever I try to call

`myFont.setFont(Font.loadFont(etc etc);`

It is unable to override the label class in the CSS file. How can this be done? Thank you!

```
.label
{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.label` is one of the built in styles that is applied to all `Node`s of type `Label`. You can remove any style class like this:

```
Label lbl = ...
lbl.getStyleClass().remove("label");
```

However I would suggest another approach that does not involve removing a style class especially one of the built ins.

As there seems to be only a selected few labels, that don't have that style you can override it on those Labels:

```
.label-override {
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
}

Label otherLbl = ...
otherLabel.getStyleClass().add("label-override);
```

Comment: Found an alternate solution as well thanks to your explanation. I can type `myLabel.getStyleClass().clear();` and it will reset any CSS documentation on my Node.

Comment: Editted previous comment for alternative solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @hotzst This is incorrect - "*Therefore you cannot remove that style from a specific Label*". A more appropriate statement should be - "*Therefore you **shouldn't** remove that style from a specific Label*"

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: thank for pointing this out, I was not aware of this. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to do it. Few of the approaches are described here :

- Define a different style-class instead of using the default `.label` and use it on your 99% of labels.

**Code :**

```
mylabel.getStyleClass().add("my-label")
```

**CSS :**

```
.my-label {
   -fx-font-size: 14pt;
   -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
}
```

- Remove the default `label` style class and set a new style class to 1% of the labels. This will remove the already present `.label` style class from the node. This seems to be an easier approach but if I were you, **I would not** go with this approach since we <3 the default styles and we want them to be applied to the respective nodes by default.

**Code :**

```
mylabel.getStyleClass().setAll("my-label");
```